# SQL - how to create a new table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am self-studying how to write SQL. I am following the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/indexes.html).

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ')' at line 1

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: it would be great if you reveal your `SQL query`

Comment: Hi! Could you post the code you have so we can diagnose the error.

Comment: You are clearly using MySQL, not Postgres - so why are you reading the Postgres manual? (And and **extremely** outdated one at that)

Comment: where is your code

Answer (score 0):

Can you add what SQL you have tried? Otherwise, this is how you create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    column1 datatype,
    column2 datatype,
    column3 datatype,
)
```